# Add custom jQuery in M2.2

Tags: magento2.2, jquery

I have written a js file which is like.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){  $('#test').click(function(){
>      Alert('coming'); }) })
```

I have created a custom theme which is based on luma and I have added that js file under namespace/theme/web/js and also included that js in Magento_Theme layout default_head_block.xml but it gives error $ is undefined.

Can someone suggest me how can I include that file

Answer (score 0):

This is used for M2 2.1.7 This will help you. Reminder this is an example.
  For default header block add following script

```
 <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>
```

I have used slick slider, so create a js file "requirejs-config.js" inside ur 
  theme folder. then add following code. eg. I have used slick.

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
              'slick.min': 'js/slick.min',            
        }
    }
  };
```

I have added slick.min.js to web/js folder

then your custom.js file

```
require(['jquery', 'slick.min'], function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function(){
       alert();
    });
  })
```

slick is my slider. this code for example, you can use this and do experiment.
  run php bin/magento setup:upgrade and then deploy

Comment: please try to do without require.js then require(['jquery'], function ($) {
     $(document).ready(function(){
       alert();
    });
  })

Comment: @Karan Adhikari - did you try .

Comment: How would I include custom.js, from xml or there is another way to do so?

Comment: after<script src="requirejs/require.js"/>  <script src="js/camlab.js"/>